# Why isn't my if statement working properly?

Tags: java, if-statement, palindrome

I'm writing a program that finds whether a word/phrase up to 8 characters is a palindrome. No matter what I put in as input, even if it is a palindrome, my program prints my else statement. I checked and made sure the code I wrote actually prints the input in reverse and it does. So I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String word, newWord;
int lengthOfWord;
char lc;//last character

    System.out.print("Enter word/phrase of 8 characters or less: ");
    word = in.nextLine();

    word = word.toLowerCase();
    newWord = word;
    lengthOfWord = word.length();
    lc = word.charAt(lengthOfWord -1);


    lc = word.charAt(lengthOfWord -1);

    if (word.length() == 2)
        newWord = lc+word.substring(0,1);
    else if (word.length() == 3)
        newWord = lc+word.substring(1,2)+word.substring(0,1);
    else if (word.length() == 4)
        newWord = lc+word.substring(2,3)+word.substring(1,2)+word.substring(0,1);
    else if (word.length() == 5)
        newWord = lc+word.substring(3,4)+word.substring(2,3)+word.substring(1,2)+word.substring(0,1);
    else if (word.length() == 6)
        newWord = lc+word.substring(4,5)+word.substring(3,4)+word.substring(2,3)+word.substring(1,2)+word.substring(0,1);
    else if (word.length() == 7)
        newWord = lc+word.substring(5,6)+word.substring(4,5)+word.substring(3,4)+word.substring(2,3)+word.substring(1,2)+word.substring(0,1);
    else if (word.length() == 8)
        newWord = lc+word.substring(6,7)+word.substring(5,6)+word.substring(4,5)+word.substring(3,4)+word.substring(2,3)+word.substring(1,2)+word.substring(0,1);
    else
        newWord = "error, not enough or too many characters";

    if (newWord == word)
        System.out.println("it is a palindrome");
    else
        System.out.println("it is not a palindrome");

    System.out.println(newWord);
```

Comment: Use `String`'s `equals` method to compare string values, not the `==` operator, which determines if two references refer to the same object.

Answer (score 4):

You could make it a lot simpler.

```
word = word.toLowerCase();
newWord = new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString();

if (newWord.equals(word))
     System.out.println("it is a palindrome");
 else
      System.out.println("it is not a palindrome");
```

Answer (score 3):

`==` means the runtime will check if they are pointing to the same address, `equals` will check if the two objects have the same content. So try to use the `equals` method to compare Strings and `==` for numbers.

Answer (score 3):

`String`s are objects.  And the string variables are merely pointers to the string object.  So, when you do `if(newWord==word)`, you're not comparing the contents of the strings, rather you're comparing the value in these pointers (the memory location the pointers point too).  You need to use `String`'s `equals` method in order to compare the contents of two strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (newWord.equals(word))
        System.out.println("it is a palindrome");
else
        System.out.println("it is not a palindrome");
```

When you use ==, the words are not compared, what is compared is the index of the two variables in memory.